# Python TypeError:string formatting when use witn open()

Tags: python

I have a list `img_list` and `type` `chapter` are all string, when i use string formatiing in `with open()` to create the .jpg file it shows `TypeError`.

So i do some test, as the result in below codes:

1. `print('./%s/%s/%d.jpg' %(title,chapter,n))` it output the correct result
2. `with open('./%s/%s/%d.jpg','wb' %(title,chapter,n))` it cause TypeError but it really as the same as 1
3. `with open('./%s/%s/'+str(n)+'.jpg','wb' %(title,chapter)) as f` still cause TypeError
4. `with open(dir+str(n)+'.jpg','wb') as f:` finally i set `dir` as `'./%s/%s/' %(title,chapter)` then it passed

I really confused about the 4 kinds of expression,why 1 and 4 are correct but 2 and 3 are uncorrect

Here's the codes:

```
dir='./%s/%s/' %(title,chapter)
    n=0
    for i in img_list:
        n+=1
        '''1.this is correct'''
        print('./%s/%s/%d.jpg' %(title,chapter,n))
        '''2.this shows TypeError'''
        with open('./%s/%s/%d.jpg','wb' %(title,chapter,n)) as f:
            f.write(requests.get(i).content)
        '''3.this shows TypeError'''
        with open('./%s/%s/'+str(n)+'.jpg','wb' %(title,chapter)) as f:
            f.write(requests.get(i).content)
         '''4.this is correct'''
        with open(dir+str(n)+'.jpg','wb') as f:
           f.write(requests.get(i).content)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `open('./%s/%s/%d.jpg','wb' %(title,chapter,n))` the format-opperator % follows 'wb' and therefor tries to operate on that string, rather than on the file-name template.

Change the line to `open('./%s/%s/%d.jpg' %(title,chapter,n),'wb' )` and it will work as expected.